# The Tinternet irresolution

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

Good time of the day. I had been wondering whether or not I can shorten "The Internet"; thus, I went online and stumbled upon the word Tinternet in the urban dictionary. Can you please tell me is it plausible to use such a word in a formal context, or one should refrain from any shortenings what so ever, given the fact that this specific word is not even included in any authorized dictionaries like Oxford, M&W, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with *the net* a very widely used short form for the Internet ?

Comment: People might say ' *T'internet* ' in a northern accent in the UK (definite article reduction) This has been used by Peter Kay in his comedy routines.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is not a reliable source! Anyone can post there and a lot of it is made up nonsense: people often post definitions that they've made up themselves, or joke definitions.

Comment: I would interpret "Tinternet" to mean the web where Tinder is operating.

Comment: And then there's this:https://www.etsy.com/shop/Tinternet

Comment: @StuartF, Didn't know about that. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

This is a deliberately joky slang word, like "intertubes" or "interwebz". It's not appropriate in a formal context and might not even be understood.

Comment: Thank you, sir.